# read binary file and display content in Jlist

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io, jpanel

How can I read binary file and display in JPanel.Up to now i have initialized a jframe,jpanel for jbutton when i run the code the button and the frame appears but when i click the show button what i need to show is data from the file here is the code that i have done.

```
    public class GraphicalDisplay{
        private JFrame cframe;
        private JButton showButton;
        public GraphicalDisplay() {

        }

    public void displayCompanyList() {
        //creating frame for the display of contents and containers and other elements like jlabel and jbutton
        cframe = new JFrame("List of Companies");
        cframe.setLocation(700,150);
        cframe.setSize(600,300);

        //creating button 
        showButton =new JButton("Show list");

        //create panel to hold button
        JPanel bpanel=new JPanel();
        bpanel.add(showButton);
        //add panel to the frame
        cframe.add(bpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cframe.setVisible(true);

        showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                 byte [] buffer =null;
                 File a_file = new File("companies.dat");
                 try
                 {
                 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("companies.dat");
                 int length = (int)a_file.length();
                 buffer = new byte [length];
                 fis.read(buffer);
                 fis.close();
                 }
                 catch(IOException e)
                 {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

Comment: Well with arbitrary binary data, how do you want to display it? (Note that that's really *not* a good way of reading a file as a byte array. Use `Files.readAllBytes` if you possibly can.)

Comment: How do you want to display it ? As a hexdump ? Only those characters that make up valid text ? Or has the binary file some structure that needs to be decoded ?

Comment: yes the binary file has structure

Comment: what would be solution if the file was just a plain text file?

Comment: *".. if the file was just a plain text file?"*  [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) ..

Comment: tried that too but non of this is working!